# JSON-LD - Email Markup - How to exclude some days between startDate and endDate

Tags: gmail, google-calendar-api, markup, schema.org, json-ld

I have got an eventReservation markup (JSON-LD) in my E-Mail.
The event should be adopted to Google Calendar (From gMail).

The Dates from this events are on:
Monday 2017-07-17 9:30 to 16:30
Tuesday 2017-07-18 9:30 to 12:30
Wednesday 2017-07-19 9:30 to 12:30
Friday 2017-07-20 9:30 to 16:30
(BUT not on Thursday)

The working code for ONE day is:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context":              "http://schema.org",
  "@type":                 "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber":     "123123123123_2",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type":               "Person",
    "name":                "Max Muster"
  },
  "modifiedTime": "2017-07-17T06:31:00+02:00",
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type":               "Event",
    "name":                "Test-Event",

    "startDate": "2017-07-17T09:30:00+02:00",
    "endDate": "2017-07-17T16:30:00+02:00",
    "performer": {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "Maximilia Muster"
        },
    "location": {
      "@type":             "Place",
      "name":              "Location-Name",
      "address": {
        "@type":           "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress":   "Str. 3",
        "addressLocality": "Locality",
        "addressRegion":   "OO",
        "postalCode":      "1234",
        "addressCountry":  "DE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**How do i exclude some days between startDate and endDate?**
**And How do i implement different startDates and endDates in the E-Mail Markup?**

*Info: A startDate as array ([2017-07-17T06:30:00+02:00][2017-07-18T06:30:00+02:00]...) does not be adopted to Google calendar.*